# trouble converting void * back to struct

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm working on a game using Box2D for physics and having trouble with void *.

Box2D fixtures have a (void*) userData field, for doors in my level, I am setting that to the address of the door information, which is a struct called NextLevel (below).

```
struct NewLevel {
    bool changed;
    std::string name;
    int x;
    int y;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    int num;
};
```

The doors are stored in the level class in `std::vector<NewLevel> doors`. In the loop that assembles each of the levels, if there is a door, I `doors.push_back(NewLevel())` and then set the data accordingly.  Then I store the `FixtureDef.userData = &doors.back()`.

However, when I go to retrieve that information, it doesn't work out. (fixB being a pointer to the fixture in contact).

`NewLevel nextDoor = *(static_cast<NewLevel*>(fixB->GetUserData()))`

Sometimes, it just works. However, at other times, it gives gibberish. When I load the next level, I clear the vector. I print the pointers out a lot, sometimes, they don't match, what would cause this? Is there a better way to pass this data?

Thanks! (I can put more code if needed)

**Edit:**

I ended up solving this by storing the b2Fixture* from box2d and the index of the item in the doors vector, rather than trying to cast/re-cast a pointer to the NewLevel and it has been working great. Thanks for all of the help, the notion of tracking the index got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, you will see that the `vector` template class must be allowed to move its data from place to place. Otherwise dynamic resizing (e.g. `push_back`) wouldn't be possible. So if you take the address of an element, and then alter the size of the vector, the address may become invalid. This is what you are seeing.

Perhaps you could just store the index of the element with `FixtureDef.userData = static_cast<void*>(doors.size()-1)` ?

Comment: That's pretty sound. I have the doors vector stored in the Level class, so I can give a pointer to it to the Contact class and then just (*doors)[index] to get my info. I'm having trouble changing the void* back to an int (It also warns me that cast to 'void*' from smaller integer type 'int').

Comment: You can use std::list instead of std::vector. List do not change address of it's elements.

Comment: Pavel: Good point! `List` is a better solution, as long as `operator[]` is not needed.